# Unity - roll cube over it's edges

Tags: animation, rotation, unity-game-engine, cube

I'm facing a problem in Unity. I have created a grid of in which's center I instatiate a cube. For the cube I created 4 animations - to rotate the cube 90° and move one field further.

This is actually working fine and also the animation is done right on EVERY field I instantiate my object.

The problem I am facing now is, that I can't make more than one move in one direction. The cube will be resettet to my original position (in this case the red cross)

[image]

So I thought of also moving the parent object of my cube (which I had to create to make the relative animation possible) and added this code:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("w")){      
            animation.Play("move_forward", PlayMode.StopAll);
            transform.parent.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward, Space.World);
        }
```

Now the cube first jumps one field further and then starts the animation. How could I achieve the result I want? (One field with one animation and then be able to continue rolling)

Comment: Is using Unity's rotation tools out of the question?  It would make life a lot easier than importing animations.

Comment: indeed, if you wanted to do it physically, just literally apply a force "around" the axis you want it to tumble on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Time.deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to apply translations over time, and not instantly:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("w")) {      
    animation.Play("move_forward", PlayMode.StopAll);
    transform.parent.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```

Review the [Time.deltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) documentation to apply speed stepping.

However as user Sandy Gifford said in the post comments, you should simplify things a lot by not using animations and simply using Transform.Rotate as well:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown("w")){      
    transform.parent.transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
    transform.parent.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
}
```